# TYPO3 pure backend extension V11.5

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-11.x

I'm using TYPO3 V11.5 with an extension, which has only a backend module.

Therefore it doesn't exist any `configPlugin` and also no `ext_localconfig` and under Configuration->TCA->Overrides no tt_content.php file.

If I try to call the backend I get the following error message:

[image: error message]

What is required to avoid this error or is it an TYPO3 bug?

**Edit**

Stupid misteake, forgot to include the extension template under `Template->Includes`!

Answer (score 0):

Without having too much code I **guess** it is because the class really does not exist! Is the file really called `BackEndController` and also the class in it `BackEndController` with an uppercase `E`?

Comment: Georg, I have an extension, which was working on V10.4 but not under 11.5, after made the required updates for 10.5. Therefore I created a new extension with ExtensinBuilder 11.0.0 also only with a backend extension. Also this extension creates the same error. So in my opinion, it has in general something  to do with setting up an extention as a pure backend extension. Because there is no configPlugin. I got the same error message with V11.5, if the `tt_content.php` was missing under `Configuration->TCA->Overrides`. Do I have to add a `tt_content.php` also for a pure backend module?

Comment: no tt_content.php is frontend only. if you can share your test extension via slack, I could maybe help out